# ¿Se puede crear un archivo de Excel desde angualr apartir de JSON?

Tags: json, angular, excel, angular7, angular6

debo generar un archivo excel con un JSON que me responde el servidor pero no encuentro librerias que hagan algo como esto la mayoria de las veces es al contrario de Excel a Json ¿Conocen alguna que me pueda servir? De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Las preguntas solicitando recursos externos como bibliotecas, enlaces, etc terminan cerradas, lee [ask]

Comment: Esto te puede servir. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704040/how-to-export-json-response-data-in-angular-7